# Getting django signals to work between applications

Tags: python, django, django-signals, saleor

I have a Django app called receipt_printer which should be printing an order when it is received using a signal. There are two apps here called: **Orders** and **receipt_printer**.

However, whenever an order is processed and fully charged I can't get the signals to work. The example below just prints out something to the console for simplicity. If I do everything inside the models.py in the Orders app it works fine.

receipt_printer/apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class ReceiptPrinterConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'receipt_printer'

    def ready(self):
        from . import signals
```

receipt_printer/signals.py

```
from django.db import models
from saleor.order.models import Order
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

def order_fully_paid_signal(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if instance.get_payment_status() == "fully-charged":
        print("This signal is working for fully paid order")
    else:
        print("This signal won't working for fully paid order")
post_save.connect(order_fully_paid_signal, sender=Order)
```

receipt_printer/**init**.py

```
default_app_config = 'receipt_printer.apps.ReceiptPrinterConfig'
```

UPDATE, also tried the below - didn't work:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Order)
def order_fully_paid_signal(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if instance.get_payment_status() == "fully-charged":
        print("This signal is working for fully paid order")
    else:
        print("This signal won't working for fully paid order")
```

Comment: Is there a typo in you receipt_printer/init.py - `default_app_conig`  instead of `default_app_config` ?

Comment: Yes sorry thats a typo, I'll correct

Comment: For clarity, the typo was only on the question. Still doesn't work

Comment: Can you try the pattern below? You may need to revert changes to apps.py and init.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add the following line to the bottom of my models.py for the Orders app:

```
from saleor.saleor_package.receipt_printer.signals import order_fully_paid_signal
```

Comment: Why had you to add the following import into your models?

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what the issue is here but below is a post_save pattern I use that does work cross-app without any changes needed to apps.py nor init.py:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=<Model>, dispatch_uid='<model>_post_save')
def <model>_post_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):

    ...
```

Comment: What will be the casing for my model name? 
eg: what if I have a model named "BookCover"?

Comment: Casing is irrelevant, you can name your functions whatever you like - note that you may run into problems if the `dispatch_uid` is not unique so just ensure that it is.